# Predicates and Int in alloy

Tags: alloy

I know the use of predicates in alloy but i was a little surprised by the below description:

```
pred locationConstraint(loc: Int -> Int){
    loc in (Int[0] + Int[1] + Int[2] + Int[3] + Int[4] + Int[5] + Int[6]) -> (Int[2] + Int[3])
 + (Int[2] + Int[3]) -> (Int[0] + Int[1] + Int[2] + Int[3] + Int[4] + Int[5])

}
```

Can someone please explain the above to me.

Comment: To whoever voted down this question, it might seem like a silly question to you, but SO is so thin on Alloy information that every little bit helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `run {}` to your model, and type `{x,y:Int | locationConstraint[x->y]}` into the evaluator to get the result:

[image]

Comment: 2 small questions. What does Int[0] mean? How do you interpret the expression (Int[0] + Int[1]) -> (Int[2] + Int[3]). Can you please explain the above in text form. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Int[0] means the singleton set of the atom of `Int` that represents the value zero. `Int[0] + Int[1]` is a union of two such singleton sets, i.e. the subset of `Int` containing the atoms `0` and `1`.

Comment: To your second question {a+b+c} -> {d+e+f} means a binary relation between the set of {a,b,c} and {d,e,f} which contains all possible pairs, i.e. it's the cartesian product of the two sets. In other words it's a complete bipartite directed graph (q.v.) of the two vertex sets {a,b,c} and {d,e,f}.